# JavaFX ComboBox border is wrong if the drop-down drops-"up"

Tags: css, javafx, combobox, styling

I am using "javafx.scene.control.ComboBox" on Java 8 and I noticed that whenever the combobox does not have room below and instead pops up, the bordering styling of the elements switches as if it still pops down.

How can I access the styling for that to fix it?

[image: ComboBox border issue]

Comment: looks like a bug .. you might consider reporting it (if still virulent in a more recent version, fx 8 is veery outdated, rarely any bugfix is/will be backported)

Comment: @Florin Mircea What is below the Combo Box on the scene? And can you show us the FXML properties for the Combo Box This is not a BUG we use Combo Boxes in JavaFX 8 all the time

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by actually extending the ComboBoxListViewSkin. In there, I've stuck a method that updates the styling, and does that by calling super.getPopup(), gets the AnchorY of that and compares it with the combo-box Y. After determining if the popup is below or above the combo, I set the correct styling on super.getListView...

Also, that method I've added, has to be called from the "ON_SHOWN" event of the combo-box.

I've tried several other variants but the damn thing just yields unstable behavior.

Comment: good that you solved it :) This answer would be even more helpful, if you added your extension method and an example of how to use it :)

Comment: I know what you mean, I thoroughly considered it. My decision was not to, and that was also the reason I did not accept my answer. I would like to encourage a better solution for this. I left some notes to help the really desperate situations, but I'd really hold for better ground on this.